# AdMob not working in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, admob

I am using `admob` in my windows phone 8 app, but it is throwing an exception -

> Ad Network Not Available

and it is not showing any banner because of the problem.

Which variable am I missing or is it the SDK issue?

```
<google:BannerAd
        AdUnitID="a1521709bd7f585" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60"  Name="AdControl" IsEnabled="True"
             AdFailed="IntubeAdFailedHandler"
             AdLeavingApplication="IntubeAdLeavingApplicationHandler"
             AdPresentingScreen="IntubeAdPresentingScreenHandler"
             AdReceived="IntubeAdReceivedHandler"/>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I thought Admob does not support Windows Phone 8 yet?

Comment: Why not! it is easily be added to WP8, infact Admob is only for wp8 and onward.

Comment: I posted in 2013 that time it was not available for Wp8

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by low ads inventory for your region and Windows Phone platform in AdMob. You can use the TestMode integration settings for Development stage as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#wp7#testmode).